# how to show display image before the data load in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-directive

I am working on ionic 4 app. my app is working properly. Issue is that now i have list of objects having different prices and details. when i load the page everything is loaded but image take 2 3 second delay after data uploaded. i dont know how to resolve this. my html and .ts code is ass follow. any help would be appreciated

```
<ion-row >
    <ion-col size="12" [ngClass]="{'featured': isFeatured() }" class="result-image"
             [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + environment.API + 'images/'
             + itemType + '/' + data.coverImage + ')'}" no-padding>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
    <ion-col size="7">{{ data.name }}</ion-col>
    <ion-col size="5">
        <ion-badge *ngIf="offer" class="offer" color="warning">{{ offer.strapline }}</ion-badge>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

and .ts code is ass follow

```
  isFeatured() {
  return this.data.promotedListing &&
  moment(this.date).isBetween(moment(this.data.promotedFrom), moment(this.data.promotedTo));
 }
```

```
checkOffers(result: Venue | Event) {
        const validOffers = [];
        if (result.offers) {
            result.offers.forEach(offer => {
                const rule = new RRule({
                    dtstart: new Date(offer.rrule.dtstart),
                    until: new Date(offer.rrule.until),
                    freq: offer.rrule.freq,
                    byweekday: offer.rrule.byweekday,
                    bysetpos: offer.rrule.bysetpos || null,
                    bymonthday: offer.rrule.bymonthday || null,
                    byyearday: offer.rrule.byyearday || null,
                    count: offer.rrule.count || null,
                    byweekno: offer.rrule.byweekno || null,
                });
                const date = new Date(this.date);
                console.log(date);
                const occurences = rule.between(moment(date).utc().startOf('date').toDate(),
                    moment(date).utc().endOf('date').toDate());
                occurences.forEach(occurance => {
                    validOffers.push(offer);
                });
            });

        }

        if (validOffers.length === 1) {
            this.offer = validOffers[0];
        }

        if (validOffers.length > 1) {
            this.offer = {
                strapline: 'Multiple offers inside',
                description: '',
                duration: '',
            };
        }
    }
```

check offer is called at ngOninIt.

Comment: this package can solve your issue, you will have to place a placeholder image : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lazyload-image

Comment: default image in not required for my client. according to him it show the real image and its animation ahold be smooth

Comment: i want smooth animation means my data and image should load smoothly

Comment: data and image load cannot be at the same time , cause different images will have different load times . Also one way is to give fadein animation to the whole list

Comment: https://prnt.sc/pzja64 this one is before the image shown and the other one is after the image display https://prnt.sc/pzjabq. All data is using like an object

Comment: @JoelJoseph please you gove me any example of faiden animation of whole list?

Comment: Maybe think about proposing this to your client: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/skeleton-text, just explain to them that best practice since images are loaded asynchronously is to substitute real images with skeleton placeholders until real content is loaded.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko thanks alot its also great idea but please you let me know one thing about it either it would be working till image display because now data load before the image and he wants smooth animation as mentioned in comment 5 above diffrent screenshoot